# QScrollArea get scroll or total offset

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt

Does QScrollArea have a way to find out how much it is scrolled? Do I need to do some accounting on all the scollContensBy() calls?
I need to get the position of the mouse relative to an image label inside QScrollArea.
I can only get the position relative to the current view, not the whole image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[QAbstractScrollArea](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html) provides methods to access its scroll bars (`horizontalScrollBar()` and `verticalScrollBar()`). Once you have that pointer, you have access to all the methods and signals available from [QScrollBar](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollbar.html) and [QAbstractSlider](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html), including `value()` and `valueChanged()`.